# Media Volume controller in DialogPreference

Tags: android, media, dialog-preference

I am trying to control media volume

But always it automatic set to zero after closing dialog.

code :

```
         DialogPreference dp = (DialogPreference)findPreference("mediavolume");
         dp.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(new OnPreferenceChangeListener() {

             public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
             SeekBar volumeBar = (SeekBar)findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
             final AudioManager manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);  


             volumeBar.setMax(manager.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));
             volumeBar.setProgress( manager.getStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC));

             volumeBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                     manager.setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC, progress,manager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);


                }
            });

                return false;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do here. You have all the important parts, the `volumebar.setMax()`, the `volumebar.setProgress()`, and the `OnSeekBarChangeListener`, but did you intend to put it in a change listener for the whole dialog? This listener is going to return false unless the dialog itself is changed.